# How to highlight a button when it is pressed in WPF xaml

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have two button styles in Styles.xaml file like MyStyleButton and MyStyleButtonClick.

I applied MyStyleButton to the existing button like below

When Button is pressed I would like to apply "MyStyleButtonClick" in xaml page by using Triggers in order to show differentiation between those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for a "GlassButton" style, with different behavior when pressed, triggered on event "IsPressed":

```
<Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder"
            CornerRadius="25,25,25,25"
            BorderThickness="4,4,4,4"
            Background="#AA000000"
            BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1.7*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="23,23,0,0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#08FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#88FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ButtonBorder">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Button, with this style, will be coded like this:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource GlassButton}" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="0,0,18.577,17.148" 
        Name="button1" 
        Height="91.456" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Width="207.764">Button</Button>
```